# Rename leaving trailing character

Tags: command-line, rename, perl

this one should be simple for anyone who knows the correct way to escape. 
I'm attempting to batch rename a few hundred files that had \u0026amp; pushed into 
the file names instead of and or &. I tried using:

`rename s/"\\u0026amp;"/"and"/g *` but and getting names like `Excision \uand Datsik - Calypso.mp3` you can see the `\u` wasn't escaped properly. What's the way to escape my
`\`??

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you're using quotes like that. Here's how I use `rename`:

```
rename 's/search/replace/' *
```

And here's it in action:

```
oli@bert:~/Desktop/rawr$ ls
pie\u333.sh
oli@bert:~/Desktop/rawr$ rename 's/\\u333/PIE/' *
oli@bert:~/Desktop/rawr$ ls
piePIE.sh
```

Your quotes seem to be throwing it off.

Comment: You're right, it was requiring it to need ANOTHER trailing slash, see above (or below, depending on post angle). Up for noticing it too.

Comment: Backslash is interpreted by the shell within double quotes (not single), so Perl sees `s/\u0026amp;/and/g`.  `\u` means "uppercase next char", which pointlessly capitalizes `0`.   So, it's equivalent to `s/0026amp;/and/g`: only the `0026amp;` is replaced and the `\u` is left behind.  Short story is you should always use singlequotes with `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed more trailing slashes evidently... =(

`rename s/"\\\u0026amp;"/"and"/g *`

Comment: If you're going to double-escape the backslashes, you should really have four: otherwise you're just relying on the shell expanding `\u` to `\u` and that won't work in other cases.